# Conditioned probability of two sequential experiences

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I calculate the probability of getting a number smaller than a previous random picked number?

Details:

I have a first independent experience where a set of n random numbers are picked from 1 to M.

(n <<< M)

From the picked numbers, I choose the smaller number.

Then, I repeat this experience again (independently).

How can I calculate the probability of this second number being smaller or equal than the first one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by a minor number?

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my mother language. I meant to say: smaller number.

Comment: Not entirely sure I am following the procedure.  If I have understood it, the two numbers are chosen in exactly the same way.  If so, then the probability that the second is smaller is $.5$, by symmetry, if the process is continuous.  otherwise it is $.5\times (1-p_{tie})$ where $p_{tie}$ denotes the probability that the two values coincide.

Comment: Yes, they are chosen in the same way, from 1 to M, but the second is only valid if smaller than the first. So the first is valid from 1 to M, but the second is only valid from 1 to the first number. For simplicity, we can consider the second number valid if smaller or equal than the first one.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean "by symmetry"?

Comment: I mean that the probability of getting $a$, then $b$ is the same as the probability of getting $b$, then $a$.  Note that switching your test to $b≤a$ does not solve the problem as the issue of the tie does not go away.

Comment: To illustrate, suppose my numbers are obtained by tossing a fair die.  Then the probability of a tie is $\frac 16$.  The probability that the second toss is strictly lower than the first is $\frac 12\times \left(1-\frac 16\right)=\frac 5{12}$.  You can check this by listing all possible rolls.

Comment: Imagine that the dice has 2^256 sides ;)

Comment: Then the exact same computation goes through.  Now $p_{tie}=2^{-256}$ so the probability you want is $\frac 12\times \left(1-2^{-256}\right)$ which is certainly very close to $.5$ (as $p_{tie}$ is very close to $0$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67592/discussion-between-pedro-fp-simoes-and-lulu).

Comment: No, sorry.  I don't like to go into private chat rooms, even to discuss math.  And, frankly, I think this discussion is exhausted.  I've given you the answer to your question and I truly don't think there are interesting avenues left to pursue.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are drawn so there is zero probability of ties and all orders are equally likely, then the probability that the $n+1^{\text{th}}$ number drawn will be smaller than all of the previous $n$ numbers drawn is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, by symmetry

An equivalent approach counting the possible orders could calculate $\frac{1 \times n!}{(n+1)!}$ to give the same answer

If you already know the smallest number drawn so far, you could make a better estimate